# Unable to remove Item from ListView control in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to remove an item from `listview` control using `RemoveAt()` function but I am getting the following error:

```
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
```

I am using the following code to remove item:

```
void remove (object sender)
{
    var item = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
    int index = PropSearchList.Items.IndexOf(item);
    PropSearchList.Items.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it in UI thread

```
Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () => PropSearchList.Items.RemoveAt(index));
```

### UPDATE:

You can use `ObservableCollection` and remove items from your source. Create an instance for your `cachedData` and rewrite come code:

```
private ObservableCollection<T> cachedData;
...
PropSearchList.ItemsSource = cachedData;
...
Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () => cachedData.RemoveAt(index));
```

Comment: How you setup `ItemsSource` property to your ListView?

Comment: I am caching data using Q42 libraries and then i assign the data like:

 var cachedData = await DataCache.GetAsync("FavouritesList", () => LoadData(SearchData));

                PropSearchList.ItemsSource = cachedData;

Comment: Afaik you should almost never use the High priority and in this case it seems completely unnecessary.